# What is the best glide speed for the DC-3 with 2 engines out?

Tags: emergency, v-speeds, dc-3

What is the best glide speed for the DC-3 with 2 engines out?

I realize we may consider best speed for ground distance traveled or best for duration - and that weight can be a factor. I can't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum glide angle for the DC-3 with power off, both propellers feathered, gear and flaps up, no wind is computed to be 3.88 degrees. This angle will give the maximum glide range. Depending on the aircraft's weight the following numbers can be applied to give the maximum distance:
20,000 lbs. Gross Wt. IAS 92K   (MPH 106),
23,000 lbs. Gross Wt. IAS 99K   (MPH 114),
26,000 lbs. Gross Wt. IAS 104   (MPH 120),
The rate of sink at 20,000 lbs gross weight is approximately 680 feet per minute (11.3 ft per sec.) at 5,000 ft of altitude.